# Multiple relations to the same model: from CakePHP 2.x to CakePHP 3.x

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0

My attempt to apply this [example](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-relations-to-the-same-model) to CakePHP3: tables `users` and `messages (id, user_id, recipient_id, body)` with two foreign keys to `id` in `users`.

The following pieces of code in `MessagesTable.php`:

```
    $this->belongsTo('Sender', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'className' => 'Users',
        'propertyName' => 'Sender'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Recipient', [
        'foreignKey' => 'recipient_id',
        'className' => 'Users',
        'propertyName' => 'Recipient'
    ]);
```

in `MessagesController.php` in `view` and `index` methods:

```
    $message = $this->Messages->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users'],
        'contain' => ['Sender'],
        'contain' => ['Recipient']
    ]);
```

in `UsersTable.php`:

```
    $this->hasMany('MessagesSent', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'className' => 'Messages',
        'propertyName' => 'MessagesSent'

    ]);

    $this->hasMany('MessagesReceived', [
        'foreignKey' => 'recipient_id',
        'className' => 'Messages',
        'propertyName' => 'MessagesReceived'
    ]);
```

and in `UsersController.php` in `view` method:

```
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['MessagesSent'],
        'contain' => ['MessagesReceived']        
    ]);
```

do not show `Related Messages` in this users `view.ctp`:

```
<h4><?= __('Related Messages') ?></h4>
    <?php if (!empty($user->messages)): ?>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Id') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('User Id') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Recipient Id') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= __('Body') ?></th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($user->messages as $messages): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= h($messages->id) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($messages->user_id) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($messages->recipient_id) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($messages->body) ?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

If I leave only `hasMany('Messages')` in `UsersTable.php` and `'contain' => ['Messages']` in `UsersController.php`, I do see `Related Messages` in the `view` above, but obviously only those, related to sender.

In both cases `add` and `edit` messages results in Error: `Table "App\Model\Table\MessagesTable" is not associated with "Users"`.

Is there a way to fix this in CakePHP3.x without adding a join table? I have a feeling that I am not properly using the aliases, but I cannot figure out where exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, unless you have something like this in MessagesTable.php:

```
$this->belongsTo('Users', []);
```

The "Table "App\Model\Table\MessagesTable" is not associated with "Users"" is correct. So in MessagesController.php you should only contain recipient and sender:

```
$message = $this->Messages->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Sender', 'Recipient'],
]);
```

About the "Related Messages" issue, you should consider that if you contain 'MessagesSent' and 'MessagesReceived', your entity will not have a 'messages' array, but two different arrays called 'messages_received' and 'messages_sent'.

Comment: Thank you! Error is gone and I can add and edit messages, this is great. I have changed everywhere in the view.ctp above 'messages' to 'messages_sent', but still nothing appears in "Related Messages". Should I also change anything in message entity itself and/or controllers?

Comment: Hi Vincent, I don't know if I understand correctly the question you are asking. As far as I can see, there is nothing else to change.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works as Daniel suggested, but it is important NOT to have

`'propertyName' => 'MessagesSent'`

and

`'propertyName' => 'MessagesReceived'`

in `UsersTable.php`!

The `view.ctp` above for e.g. sent messages should look like this:

```
<h4><?= __('Related Sent Messages') ?></h4>
<?php if (!empty($user->messages_sent)): ?>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col"><?= __('Id') ?></th>
        <th scope="col"><?= __('User Id') ?></th>
        <th scope="col"><?= __('Recipient Id') ?></th>
        <th scope="col"><?= __('Body') ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($user->messages_sent as $messages): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= h($messages->id) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($messages->user_id) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($messages->recipient_id) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($messages->body) ?></td>

    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```